# Reducing the width of table cells

Tags: tables, width, column-width

does anybody know if tabular has any properties where we are able to adjust the width of individual columns?

I'm specifically wanting to reduce the space around the arrows and also around the text on the left-hand side. I'm essentially trying to reduce the width of the whole thing without changing the size of the tables. I'm ideally wanting a solution that doesn't involve making any new commands and was hoping there is something simple to do this.

I also know that the way I have done my arrows is not the most efficient, but I wanted to make the arrows a little longer than what was given. So if anybody has a simple solution to this too, then that would be amazing.

Thankyou! :D
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{permute}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[hmargin = 1.25 in, bmargin=1 in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rccccccc}
& Text && Text && Text && Text   \\[0.25cm]
\begin{tabular}{c} TextText \\ Text: \end{tabular} 
  & \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{TAB}(e,0.7cm,0.7cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|}  1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1 \end{TAB}} & \(\xrightarrow[\phantom{Spa}]{Text}\)
  & \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{TAB}(e,0.7cm,0.7cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|}  1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1 \end{TAB}} & \(\xrightarrow[\phantom{Spa}]{Text}\)
  & \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{TAB}(e,0.7cm,0.7cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|}  1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1 \end{TAB}} & \(\xrightarrow[\phantom{Spa}]{Text}\)
  & \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{TAB}(e,0.7cm,0.7cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|}  1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1 \end{TAB}} \\[1.5cm]

\begin{tabular}{c} TextText \\ Text: \end{tabular} 
  & \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{TAB}(e,0.7cm,0.7cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|}  1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1 \end{TAB}} & \(\xrightarrow[\phantom{Spa}]{Text}\)
  & \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{TAB}(e,0.7cm,0.7cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|}  1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1 \end{TAB}} & \(\xrightarrow[\phantom{Spa}]{Text}\)
  & \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{TAB}(e,0.7cm,0.7cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|}  1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1 \end{TAB}} & \(\xrightarrow[\phantom{Spa}]{Text}\)
  & \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{TAB}(e,0.7cm,0.7cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|}  1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1 \end{TAB}} \\[1.5cm]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your example complete, for example add the definition of `TAB` environment.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ  Sorry, I forgot about that one. I can't remember which one it is as I've got a lot in my document at the moment, so I've just put in the packages I have for the document.

Comment: The `\documentclass` line is also indispensable. In general, it is suggested to always provide a minimal working example, aka [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TAB` environment is provided by `easytable` package. From its [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/easy/doc/doctable.pdf), in `\begin{TAB}(e,0.7cm,0.7cm)`, the minimum x- and y-size of each cell are both set to `0.7cm`.

Therefore it works to use a smaller dimension, for example `0.5cm`:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{rccccccc}
& Text && Text && Text && Text   \\[0.25cm]
\begin{tabular}{c} TextText \\ Text: \end{tabular} 
  & \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{TAB}(e,0.5cm,0.5cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|}  1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1 \end{TAB}} & \(\xrightarrow[\phantom{Spa}]{Text}\)
  & \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{TAB}(e,0.5cm,0.5cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|}  1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1 \end{TAB}} & \(\xrightarrow[\phantom{Spa}]{Text}\)
  & \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{TAB}(e,0.5cm,0.5cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|}  1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1 \end{TAB}} & \(\xrightarrow[\phantom{Spa}]{Text}\)
  & \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{TAB}(e,0.5cm,0.5cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|}  1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1 \end{TAB}} \\[1.5cm]

\begin{tabular}{c} TextText \\ Text: \end{tabular} 
  & \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{TAB}(e,0.5cm,0.5cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|}  1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1 \end{TAB}} & \(\xrightarrow[\phantom{Spa}]{Text}\)
  & \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{TAB}(e,0.5cm,0.5cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|}  1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1 \end{TAB}} & \(\xrightarrow[\phantom{Spa}]{Text}\)
  & \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{TAB}(e,0.5cm,0.5cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|}  1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1 \end{TAB}} & \(\xrightarrow[\phantom{Spa}]{Text}\)
  & \adjustbox{valign=c}{\begin{TAB}(e,0.5cm,0.5cm){|c|c|c|}{|c|c|c|}  1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1  \\   1 &  1 &  1 \end{TAB}} \\[1.5cm]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}` is used to reduce the column separation in `tabular` environment, which is the separation around `TAB` environments and/or arrows.